# Issue in getting the values from list of strings in rest java

Tags: java, string, mongodb, rest

I am getting the issue while getting values from list parameter after passing string parameter in rest service. Below is the code:

```
@POST
@Path("/GetData")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
public Demo(@FormParam("Input_String") List Input_String)
        throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Parameters list1 is:" + Input_String);
    System.out.println("Parameters list2 is:" + Input_String.get(0));
    return null;
}
```

Passing string in rest service is:

> Input_String: ["A", "B", "C"]

My output is:

```
Parameters list1 is:[["A", "B", "C"]]
Parameters list2 is:["A", "B", "C"]
```

But desired output is:

```
Parameters list1 is:["A", "B", "C"]
Parameters list2 is: "A"
```

Please specify how to get the values like "A", "B" or "C" using `Input_String.get(0)`, `Input_String.get(1)` and `Input_String.get(2)` methods. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The double braces show you that you are dealing with a List of Lists. So `Input_String.get(0));` itself is a list and if you want to select the first element of that again you need to call the get method again on it.

Comment: thanks but calling again get method i.e. Input_String.get(0).get(0) is showing error as seems not applicable!

Comment: Thats because you are using a Raw Type List so java doesn't know what `Input_String.get(0)` is and just treats it as `Object`. You could try casting it: `((List)Input_String.get(0)).get(0);`

Comment: but again showing error: "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List" for ((List)Input_String.get(0)).get(0).

Comment: What `Content-Type` are you using when calling the REST endpoint?

Comment: try change parameter type from `List Input_String` to `List<String> Input_String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list contains list inside list.

So try:
`Input_String.get(0).get(0)`

You must use `List<List<String>>` in method parameter in order to make this code working.

P.S.: use java naming convention, variable name should start in lower case. And you should follow camelCase.

Edit: As a workaround you can try this solution:

```
String data = Input_String.get(0).toString();
String[] items = data.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\s", "").split(",");

String val = items[0];
```

Comment: thanks, but using List<List<String>> in method parameter showing rest service error to me: "javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception"

Comment: Try using `String [][] ` in method parameter and use `Input_String[0[0]` to get data.

Comment: getting same error using String [][], not sure where it goes wrong!

Comment: Can you tell me exact error message, which you are getting

Comment: Thats showing this error:

HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

Comment: I have added one code snippet (edit section) for current code having single list in function parameter. Try this.